# Where does Highcharts local export server (Using java+phantomjs) create images in local system?

Tags: highcharts, export

1. I set up my local export server using `java & phantomjs`, it is working fine. But when I give a request from client side application to the local export server for (*PNG* or *JPEG* or *PDF*) it automatically saves in local system directory, instead of showing a pop-up to user for saving or opening.

For some time I noticed it was showing a pop-up, then automatically it stops showing pop-up and directly saving in the download folder of local system.

Another scenario is even I am using highcharts export server same problem of pop up not showing to user, but file saving properly in users local download folder.

2. My second question is where local export server creates the image in local system. So that I can refer that folder and email that file to the user.

Any help is appreciated.